# Missing Control in Excel Forms

Tags: excel, vba

I was given an Excel spreadsheet which has multiple Excel Forms inside. 
One of Forms can not be launched because apparently a control is missing. 
As usual the original developer is here anymore hence I need to find out what kind of control it is and how to obtain it.

Any ideas? I used SysInternal DebugView but haven't managed to see anything to point me in the right direction.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you view the code? Compile? Check references?

Comment: I use forms a lot and you can get some extraordinarily unhelpful error messages.  But I am struggling to identify what would notice if you deleted a control.  The code which addressed the control would give a compile or run time error but not "control missing."  When does this message appear?  What is the exact message?

Comment: It sounds to me like there is a control on the form that is not registered on your computer. Perhaps in design view it looks like a box with a red X. In the Immediate window, get the count of controls with this:  ``? YourFormName.Controls.Count``. If the count is higher than you expect that might indicate that you can't even see the problematic control. At that point, loop through the control names to identify the one to delete. (e.g. ``? YourFormName.Controls(1).Name``).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the control is missing from the form?  In my experience this type of thing is normally caused because the DLL the control belongs to isn't registered on your computer.

Open the spreadsheet in Excel and go into the VBE. Click Tools -> References and check to see if any of the references are marked as missing.